# How to prevent form resubmit when I need to display post data in same time?

Tags: php, html, post, get

Let's imagine html login code in index.php

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
 <input name="Login">
 <input name="Password">
 <input type="submit" value="Check">
</form>
```

and php code in index.php file before html

```php
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['Login"]))
    {
    //check for auth 1*
    }
    ?>
```

1* if check failed,in that page we need to show something like "You entered wrong login or password..." and also display fields to fill.But now user can click F5 as many time as he wants and get same message shown,as soon as, all parameters are sent again in Post.What I need is: show error message,but when user click refresh button,don't post parameters again.
So how can I get around this issue?
As I understand PRG pattern wouldn't work here.Is it a good way to set a cookie,redirect to same page,show message if cookies exist and remove cookie?

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['LoginError']))
{
    echo 'You entered invalid login or password';
    setcookie('LoginError','',time()-3600,'/');
}
else if(isset($_POST['Login']))
{
    //check here for invalid values
    //if there is error do next
    setcookie('LoginError','1',time()+84600,'/');
    header("location: index.php");
}
```

but in my opinion,it's not good way

Comment: Resending the post is normal behavior in browsers and can't changed. But you can store the data (ie. error message) in session, redirect to same or another page (GET method) and the show the message. One alternative is to pass the message as parameter within the url, but it's not so nice.

Comment: You'll need a little javascript to get the goal

Comment: Javascript?I don't want to move login code out of index.php

Comment: @haby, yes I know that that is usual behavior.I attached example of way you said using cookies.Is it right away?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read it carefully enough. Yes that is they way to do that. But personally, I would prefer to keep it in the session.

Comment: Why would a user keep refreshing the page if the page says their login is incorrect?  A normal user would try re-entering their information instead.  A denial of service attack would be using something like cURL not a browser and F5.

Comment: Yeah,you are absolutely right.But agree,this does not look good

Comment: I have just tested something like that with facebook and some other popular sites.They all have "anti-refresh" system.